# Write $\frac1{60}$ as sum of two fractions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many ways are there of writing $\frac1{60}$ as the sum of two unit fractions?

So far I have worked out this for any number:

```
1/n = 1/(n(n+1)) + 1/(n+1)
```

So we have so far:

```
1/120 + 1/120 = 1/3660 + 1/61 = 1/60
```

Comment: Pick $p$ to be anything you like ... $\frac{1}{60}= \frac{p-1}{60p}+\frac{1}{60p}$. ... but dont choose $p$ to be zero !

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit [unit fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_fraction) mean $1/n$.

Comment: Oh ... Egyptian fractions (numerator is $1$) ... now the question is much more interesting.

Comment: @Piquito See the above edit

Comment: @jdoe: Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**
$$
\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{60} \implies y=60+\frac{3600}{ x-60}
$$

Comment: The question is about $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{60}$

Comment: @Piquito (and jdoe), if you start with the concluding equation and work backwards, you'll see that Leox merely mistyped a $60$ instead of a $1\over60$ in the opening equation.  (I nearly did the same in my answer, but caught it in time.)

Comment: Sorry, corrected

Comment: @Leox, ping me if piquito and jdoe delete their comments, so that we can delete the entire exchange.

Answer (score 4):

With the understanding $ab\not=0$, we have

$${1\over60}={1\over a}+{1\over b}\iff ab=60(a+b)\iff(a-60)(b-60)=3600$$

This implies $a=m+60$ and $b=n+60$, where $3600=mn$, with the one exception of $m=n=-60$.  Since $3600=2^4\cdot3^2\cdot5^2$, there are $(4+1)(2+1)(2+1)=45$ factorizations with $m,n\gt0$, hence $90$ factorizations in all, of which $89$ give solutions for $a$ and $b$.

If you want to restrict to $a,b\gt0$, then there are just the $45$ solutions, corresponding to $m,n\gt0$ (since $|m|$ and $|n|$ cannot both be less than $60$).  If you want to further restrict to $a\ge b\gt0$, there is $1$ solution with $a=b$ and $22$ solutions with $a\not=b$, for a total of $23$ solutions.